# MVC basecontroller doesn't return to controller after Initializing ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

First off all i'm fairly new to C# and ASP.NET (mainly program java).

I've got a BaseController where i want to fill a viewbag for all my other controllers to use. I also set some session data and create some cookies. This is the basecontroller:

```
    public abstract partial class BaseController : Controller
{
    // GET: Base
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        try
        {
            //Checks if the user is logged in
            if (requestContext.HttpContext.Session["customer"] != null)
            {
                ViewBag.Customer = requestContext.HttpContext.Session["customer"];
                ViewBag.Points = requestContext.HttpContext.Session["points"];
                ViewBag.CardNumber = requestContext.HttpContext.Session["cardNumber"];
            }

            //Gets the products to be displayed
            var products = ProductList.Instance.AsQueryable();
            ViewBag.Products = products;

            //Checks to see if the user has a cart added to his requestContext.HttpContext.Session
            if (requestContext.HttpContext.Session["cart"] == null)
            {
                requestContext.HttpContext.Session["cart"] = new Cart();
            }
            Cart cart = (Cart)requestContext.HttpContext.Session["cart"];

            ViewBag.CartCount = cart.Count();
            if (requestContext.HttpContext.Session["ticketID"] == null)
            {
                requestContext.HttpContext.Session["ticketID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
            }

            //Adds a cookie to the user with his selected theme
            HttpCookie cookieUserTheme = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["cookieUserTheme"];
            if (cookieUserTheme != null)
            {
                requestContext.HttpContext.Session["UserPref"] = UserModel.GetThemeByName(cookieUserTheme.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                requestContext.HttpContext.Session["UserPref"] = UserModel.GetThemeByName("5");
                var cookie = new HttpCookie("cookieUserTheme", ((UserPref)requestContext.HttpContext.Session["UserPref"]).ID);
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90);
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
            ViewBag.UserPref = requestContext.HttpContext.Session["UserPref"];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
}
```

And this is the controller.

```
    public class AdminController : BaseController
{
    // GET: Admin
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Themes = SiteMethods.GetAllThemes();
        return View();
    }
```

But when this is done running it just goes to the following ASP.NET page 
[image]

What am i doing wrong? Do i need a redirect from my basecontroller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're overriding `Controller.Initialize()` with your own initialization logic, you need to call `base.Initialize(requestContext)` to continue with the regular initialization process:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);

    // rest of your code
    // ...
}
```

Otherwise, `this.ControllerContext` (that is being used internally by several properties), would be `null`.

See [Source](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerBase.cs#L109)

Comment: Oke i missed this! It's wierd that this is not easier to find. But it works now thank you!